# Js error with && operator

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var hp ='geo'
2==2 && hp += 'jio'
```

why i am getting error as 
 :- Reference Error: Invalid left hand side in assignment

''//''///'//

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Because it's evaluated as `(2==2 && hp) += 'jio'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an unexpected assignment at `hp += 'jio'` preceded by the logical operator `&&`. That is the reason to get error `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

When working with [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) notice that the precedence of operators, in this case `&&`, determines the order they are applied when evaluating an expression. You can override operator precedence by using parentheses.

In this case, if you want to modify the variable `hp`, you should do it using parentheses because with the parentheses the right-hand side of the initialization is executed as a single expression.

Code:

```js
var hp = 'geo';

2 == 2 && (hp += 'jio');

console.log(hp);
```